# Crash when setting badge on tab bar in objective C

Tags: objective-c

This line of code crashes. How to check if tabor item is not nil then setting badge?

```
[self.tabController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0].badgeValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", num];
```

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_CTNativeGlyphStorage
>   tabBar]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15029cfd0'

I checked it by this line of code, but it didn't solve the problem.

```
if (self.tabController.tabBar.items != nil)   { }
```

Comment: use this condition  - if(! (item == nil || item == (id)[NSNull null]) )

Comment: log the self.tabController value, see if it is a actual tab bar controller or is it something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are setting the badge value before the tab controller is even presented or fully initiated, then there wont be anything at index 0 as yet. There is no need for the tab controller to initiate everything until time comes for presentation, for memory usage purposes. You can keep a reference to each instance of `UITabBarItem` and set the badge value on them. Or you are going to have to wait until viewDidAppear is called, ensuring all UITabBarItems are fully instantiated...

I cant assume anything else here without seeing the rest of your code.